# Saving related model instance from model method with Flask AppBuilder and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-appbuilder

In Flask AppBuilder, for one of my model (Parent) views, I have a post_add method which triggers a method for this instance of the model:

```
def post_add(self, item):
    item.create_children()
```

As the name indicates, from that method I want to create children. Coming from Django I'm used to making my models fat (Putting some of the logic in the model). But while I know how to instantiate a new object in memory for the Child model, I am confused as to how I would save it. I can't get a hold of the current db session to add() the Child, and I'm wondering whether the way I'm doing this makes sense in Flask AppBuilder. Here's my create_children method definition inside the Parent model class:

```
def create_children(self):
    for i in range(self.num_children):
        c = Child(some_prop=self.prop)
        c.parent = self
        # And here I'm lost as to how to save each children.
        get_session().add(c)
        get_session().commit()
```

Of course get_session() won't work here, since there's no get_session defined in my module. I basically have two questions, is this the correct way to proceed with Flask AppBuilder? Should I move this code back to views.py? And wherever this method is defined, how do I go about saving the new children I've created? I'm suspected there is a helper method/function for this, but I'm not able to find it from the docs.

Thank you,

Comment: It looks like I could use dm = SQLAInterface(Child) and then dm.add(c), but it looks like I should be doing this from views.py rather than models.py in Flask AppBuilder rather.

Comment: Were you able to get this working? I have a similar use case, although instead of creating child records, I want to dump my filtered model instance to file. I will look at the SQLAInterface, since it does look like you can customize the action in the view.

Answer (score 0):

On the docs you have: https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#flask.ext.appbuilder.base.AppBuilder.get_session

So you can get SQLAlchemy session like this (on your view):

self.appbuilder.get_session